# How do Swapchain minImageCount and VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR relate to each other?

Tags: vulkan

If we assign `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR.presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR;` as I understand, we have a single buffer and the image is being presented to the surface immediately,
but at the same time `SwapChainDetails.surfaceCapabilities.minImageCount = 2;` on my GTX 1070.
Does `minImageCount` mean that minimum number of buffers should be 2 ?
How does it even work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't relate to each other at all. How many buffers you have has nothing to do with how they get displayed.

Immediate presentation means that, when you present an image, it is displayed immediately. As stated in the standard:

> the presentation engine does not wait for a vertical blanking period to update the current image

If the presentation engine only allowed you one swapchain image, then this would mean that the acquire would have to wait until the image is finished being shown. This would make immediate presentation pointless.

Now, you might think that acquiring such an image ought to happen immediately. But that would mean that you could render to the image while the presentation engine is still reading from it, causing potential corruption. But that's *not* what immediate presentation is for. Immediate presentation changes nothing about the ownership dynamics between the presentation engine and user code; it only changes the timing of how swapchain images are presented.

The ability to write to an image that is actually being presented is governed by the "shared" present modes (`VK_PRESENT_MODE_SHARED_DEMAND_REFRESH_KHR` and `VK_PRESENT_MODE_SHARED_CONTINUOUS_REFRESH_KHR`).

Comment: I would argue that they don't relate to each other *"at all"*. To achieve a non-blocking acquire behavior (assuming 1 frame in flight) in immediate mode you need at least 2 images, however in mailbox you need at least 3. This should be included in the answer more explicitly.